# jQuery width of element added in loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make all the images inside a wrapper div to be next to each other. I have set the height of the images to 100% and the width to auto, position absolute, top: 0. I need to make a jQuery code that calculates the width of the image and sets the left position of second image to width of first image. All the images will have the same width.
[image]

I have this not-working, incomplete code, that I have fight with

```
$('.page-wrap .portfolio-item').each(function(i){
    var width = $('.portfolio-item').width();
        $(this)
        .animate({left: width});
    });
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/en9ub923/

Comment: What did you try so far? I need a lot of things too, but... .)

Comment: @kmsdev I think it's useless to put it here because it's irrelevant. I even stuck on getting the width of the image.

Comment: We can (hope) help you from the code side, but we also need to see what you made to work on it. It's better than nothing.

Comment: I'm wondering, why do you have to calculate the width with jQuery, you can use floats in css, that will automatically place it right after the element

Comment: If you could post just a bit more of the code or a jsfiddle we could help more. Off the top of my head you may want to look at flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I put it in the post. http://jsfiddle.net/en9ub923/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you need to be able to scroll through the contents, you can do something like this (see the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oouu6yq/1/)):

Output:

[image: flexbox-with-overflow]

HTML:

```
<div class="overflow-container">
    <main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </main>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
main {
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100vw;

    div {
        background: lightgreen;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 60px;

        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
    }
}

.overflow-container {
    height: 64px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

---

**Old answer**

If you're willing to not support some older browsers (well, actually just use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) and you won't have to worry about that), you could try CSS `flex-box` (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oouu6yq/)):

SCSS:

```
main {
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap; // keep the elements on the same line
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    background: lightgreen;
    flex-grow: 1; // every element will take up equal space
    height: 60px;

    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 2px;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: flexbox]

The width of the children fits to the container (the children could be anything, `img`s included.)

Comment: Thank you, but it has to get out of the window in right side, because I will have some dozens of images.

Comment: @RazvanCuceu, you can just add another container with fixed width on the outside, and set `overflow-x: scroll`.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddle with css only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/se3bjch4/1/

Why not use for your img css:

`display: inline-block;`

or:

`float:left;`

!?

Or change your code to this to go with your approach:

```
var all_images_width = 0;
$('.page-wrap .portfolio-item').each(function(i, val){
    var width = $('.portfolio-item').width();
    $(this).animate({left: all_images_width});
    all_images_width += width;
});
```

Comment: because I want all the images to stay in the same line, not to go on other line

Comment: @RazvanCuceu oh are you trying to do this on page resize and making it responsive?

Comment: Edited to support images with different widths... reset `all_images_width` variable every time before you run the loop.

Comment: you could use the css property `white-space: nowrap;` on the images parent element to prevent them from wrapping to the next line. If you are using absolute positioning this doesn't apply.

Comment: @RazvanCuceu I may suggest looking how bootstrap/foundation does their grid system.

Comment: @RazvanCuceu here you go for bootstrap's grid system only, in css which is preferred for this kinda thing: https://github.com/zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only

Comment: I think I wasn't understood. I have a page that scrolls horizontally with some images with 100% height one next to each other. For some reason nowrap doesn't work (it doesn't work even in fiddle from post). So I want to arrange them with relative positioning, by calculating the left position of each image. It has to remain responsive, and calculate the width of each image.

Comment: @dcardoso You...you da real MVP! Thank you!